# Get DOMXpath results in HTML format

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm fetching data from another website using `file_get_contents()`, but I need to extract a multiple tables records with class inputpanelfields,

```
$d = new DOMDocument  
libxml_use_internal_errors(true)  
$d->loadHTML($html)   
$table = $x->query('//table[contains(@class, "inputpanelfields")]')
```

How can I do this?

Comment: $html = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com'); 

$d = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$d->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();
$x = new DOMXPath($d);
$table = $x->query('//table[contains(@class, "inputpanelfields")]'); i want the cpmlete data in html format.

Answer (score 0):

[`DomDocument::saveHTML()`](HTTP://php.net/domdocument.savehtml) takes an argument to only save a subset of the document. So you can for example output the HTML of the first matched table like this:

```
echo $d->saveHTML($table[0]);
```

Comment: $html = file_get_contents('example.com');
$d = new DOMDocument; 
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$d->loadHTML($html); 
libxml_clear_errors();
$x = new DOMXPath($d); 
$table = $x->query('//table[contains(@class, "inputpanelfields")]');   i m using this complete code bro...bt this returns me a string...can u pls give me the com plete code how to save it html format

Comment: It's a HTML string, what more would you want? Save it to a file? Then use `saveHTMLFile()` instead.

Comment: sir i want to print the data in same format from i fetched the data...like if i fetched data from table them i want to print data in table format